# What are the syntax requirements on Meteor Angular UI.Router linking?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, components

I am following the angular-meteor tutorial at: http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/routing-and-multiple-views

I understand most of the routing, but I do not see where all the parts tie together. So here's my thought process.

I the routes, I notice the :partyId.

```
.state('parties', {
        url: '/parties',
        template: '<parties-list></parties-list>'
      })
          .state('partyDetails', {
            url: '/parties/:partyId',
            template: '<party-details></party-details>'
          });
```

And in < **parties-list** >, I can see "this.partyId = $stateParams.partyId" being defined. 
**#1. How is :partyId and $stateParams.partyId related?** 
**#2. The directive is called "partyDetails" whereas the template is < party-details >... is this an implied name given by Angular?**

```
angular.module('socially').directive('partyDetails', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'party-details.html',
      controllerAs: 'partyDetails',
      controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
        this.partyId = $stateParams.partyId;
      }
    }
  });
```

Next... inside the **party-list.html** page (NOT party-details.html), there is a ui-sref link:

```
  <li ui-sref="partyDetails({ partyId: party._id })" ng-repeat="party in partiesList.parties">
    {{party.name}}
    <p>{{party.description}}</p>
    <button ng-click="partiesList.removeParty(party)">X</button>
  </li>
```

But in the < **party-list** > directive there is no mention of any variable or function called "partyDetails". 
**#3.What is the ui-sref referencing? How does it compare to "< a href="/parties/{{party._id}}" >" that is used further in the tutorial.** 

**#4. Finally, is there anything that I should know about Meteor or Angular UI.Router in regards to things that are implied/abstracted away?**

Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's same. If you declare parameters in query string like :partyId, you will received an object stateParams with keys are these parameters and values are proportional string in your segment of url.
2. It's coding conversation of Angular Js. You can check it out for more example. 
   https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
3. Not problem if you use correct anywhere. But what is happened if you want change link or url structure? Example: href="/home" appear more than 20 html pages. And you want change all to "/homepage". Why???. With router, you need only change url state in the router.js file. Ok?
4. Angular-meteor is one of ways help you build your apps with angular. So everything related angular, you can find separate. Example you can read about angular ui router or all package of angularui in this link https://angular-ui.github.io

Comment: Informative! Thank you, but could you clarify #3, specifically what party._id is doing as a parameter of partyDetails?

Comment: Yes. Obviously. You declare in your state that the 2nd segment is partyId, so ui-router will know party._id is partyId